# Protecting from merging branch into develop in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using Gitlab community edition: 11.3 (self hosted) and would like to protect developers from merging branches into develop.

According to documentation, I've setup a protected branch setting on develop,  I've choose that No One should be able to merge into develop

I opened a branch in source tree, did a small change in my new branch and pushed it,  later i checked into develop , clicked on "Merge" , choose merge from log and picked the commit on "new_branch".

It doesn't seem to block my merge , i can see in Gitlab Ui -

"Merge branch 'new_branch' into develop"

What am i missing here?

Comment: You are a maintainer. So you can merge into develop.

Comment: Have you try with a developer account ?

Comment: I am not a maintainer ,  i have done it from a "developer" account